# Is there a way to detect padding bits in a bitfield?

Tags: c++, bit-fields, static-assert

I extensively utilize bit-fields in my C++ embedded application, and I have encountered a problem. Below is an example showcasing my usage:

```cpp
struct {
    uint8_t /* Reserved */ : 3;
    uint8_t foo : 3;
    uint8_t bar : 3;
} bits;
```

To ensure that I have correctly specified the number of bits in a bit-field, I employ the `static_assert(...)` mechanism:

```cpp
// assertion fails due to 1 extra bit
static_assert(sizeof(bits) == sizeof(uint8_t));
```

This approach allows me to verify if I have surpassed the size limitation. However, I am currently unable to determine whether there are any padding bits in the `struct`. Is there a method to detect such situations?

```cpp
struct {
    uint8_t /* Reserved */ : 3;
    uint8_t foo : 3;
    uint8_t bar : 1;
} bits;
// assertion passes, but I want it to fail, because one bit is padding
static_assert(sizeof(bits) == sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Comment: I'd recommend manually doing the bit shift operations and rely on the compiler optimizing out the additional code for doing so: https://godbolt.org/z/e7Kad7Y4s

Comment: @fabian Extraordinary example, thanks.

Comment: That's one way to side-step the vagaries in the C++ specification, but does nothing to assert that the right number of bits are declared. Most compilers do sane things with bitfields, so this kind of overkill should be avoided. The only real issue for portable code is endianness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang's `-Wpadded` does exactly what you want.

If you are not using clang, you can rename your unnamed bitfields into something like `Reserved1` through `ReservedN`. Then you can use [`std::has_unique_object_representations`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations) which tells you if your class has padding or not:

```cpp
struct {
    [[deprecated("This field should not be used")]] uint8_t Reserved1 : 2;
    uint8_t foo : 3;
    uint8_t bar : 3;
} bits;

// If `Reserved1` had a bitsize of 3, it would have padding and this would fail
static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<decltype(bits)>);
```

Comment: Although it comes with a drawback, this is the best solution I saw. By the way, it's really hard to understand the actual purpose of the trait you shared. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to get the exact amount of bits in a bit-field using `sizeof`, or any other way.

### Problems with Padding in Bit-Fields

The `sizeof` operator gives you the amount of bytes that your `struct` occupies, not the amount of bits. In your second example, your bit-field consists of `7` bits, and assuming that bytes are `8` bits, the line:

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(bits) == sizeof(uint8_t));
```

is checking `1 == 1`, since your `struct` is padded up to one byte.

Furthermore, mixing different member types can result in way more bits than one would expect:

```cpp
struct {
    int a: 3;
    short b: 3;
} bits;

static_assert(sizeof(bits) == 1);
```

This gives us the error message:

> ```cpp
> <source>:5:28: error: static assertion failed
>     5 | static_assert(sizeof(bits) == 1);
>       |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
> <source>:5:28: note: the comparison reduces to '(4 == 1)'
> ```

Even though we only use `6` bits for `a` and `b`, our `bits` occupies `4` bytes.

Ultimately, the amount of padding between bit-field members is implementation-defined, so you cannot rely on any specific amount of bits or bytes.
You can only hope that the compiler laid the bit-field out the way you intended, and perhaps use `static_assert` with an upper bound for the bit-field size in bytes.

*Note: with the non-standard [`[[gnu::packed]]`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute, the above example would have compiled.*

For more information, see [the cppreference article on bit-fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

### Using Macros as a Workaround

We cannot detect the exact amount of bits, but we can use a macro so that we simply know the amount:

```cpp
// This list is being used to define the bit-field members
// and to compute the sum of bits.
#define LIST \
  E(char, , 3) \
  E(char, foo, 3) \
  E(char, bar, 1)

// Define what an entry in the list means.
#define E(type, name, size) type name: size;

struct {
// LIST expands to char: 3; char foo: 3; char bar: 1;
    LIST
} bits;

// Re-define what an entry means.
#undef E
#define E(type, name, size) +size

// LIST expands to +3 +3 +1
constexpr int bits_bits = LIST;

#undef E
#undef LIST

// This assertion passes, since we have 7 bits in total.
static_assert(bits_bits == 7);
// This assertion fails, but would have passed if we had 8 bits.
// We could also check if bits_bits is a multiple of 8 with
// bits_bits % 8 == 0.
static_assert(sizeof(bits) * 8 == bits_bits);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to do it *nicely*.

But, you can deliberately add one more bit field and check that the size increases.

```
struct {
    uint8_t /* Reserved */ : 3;
    uint8_t foo : 3;
    uint8_t bar : 1;
#ifdef DEBUG
    uint8_t BOOM : 1;
#endif
} bits;
#ifdef DEBUG
static_assert(sizeof(bits) > sizeof(uint8_t)); // Will assert in debug mode because there are insufficient bits
#else
static_assert(sizeof(bits) == sizeof(uint8_t)); // Will NOT assert
#endif
```

Of course, this only helps you if the changed struct layout doesn't make the rest of the program explode.

Comment: Although it looks quite ugly, it works well. An improvement is maybe to leave the extra bit unnamed because it might create ambiguity. Some dude might define a bit named `BOOM` :)

Comment: Yeah, that was just to draw attention to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow for a bit of extra declaration with a constexpr helper function then testing both too many or not enough bits (at 1 bit resolution) is possible at compile time like this:

```
#include <array>

// create a constexpr to see if all bit field constants
// add up to the size of the underlying type.
// if not then assert at compile time
template<typename underlying_t, std::size_t...sz>
static constexpr auto checked_bit_fields()
{
    // the numbers will be returned as an array
    std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(sz)> bit_layout{ sz... };

    // (sz + ...) is fold expression calculating the sum of the bit fields
    // 8 * sizeof calculates the size in bits of the underlying type.
    static_assert((sz + ...) == 8ul * sizeof(underlying_t));
    return bit_layout;
}

struct bits_t
{
private:
    // the template parameters with number of bits per field.
    // if the sum of the bitfield sizes do not match the underlying type size
    // the code will not compile (test it out)
    static constexpr auto bits = checked_bit_fields<uint8_t, 2, 3, 3>();

    // regretably the standard does not allow for a structured binding here
    // so I could not do [unused,foo_bits,bar_bits] = checked_bit_fields<uint8_t,2,2,3>(); 
    // an we need to access the bit field sizes from the array

public:
    uint8_t : bits[0]; // == 2
    uint8_t foo : bits[1]; // == 3
    uint8_t bar : bits[2]; // == 3 
};


int main()
{
    bits_t bits;
    bits.foo = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely fabulous approach_(for me)_. There are just a couple of drawbacks. Firstly, I'm not able to create unnamed structs. I need it because I use the bit-field structs in unions.  Secondly, I might make a mistake while indexing the bit length array. Anyway, I absolutely liked it.

Comment: What's unnamed about the struct? This is just the struct declaration, not an instance of it yet.  You can still make an instance in a union (I suppose, I never need unions, std::variant is better in C++). And yes the indexing in the array is really the weak bit (that's why comment on structured binding is there)...